# RxJava call method if button was pressed 4 times during last 3 seconds

Tags: android, rx-java

I'm absolutely new in RxJava, so probably sorry.
There are quite a lot of operators in RxJava and I can't find some that will satisfy me. I want to run method if button was pressed 4 times during last 3 seconds. So I have BehaviorSubject and it call onNext() method every time when button is pressed. And now I need to parse this flow in some way and call onComplete() method in my Observer.

Comment: did you check the `window` operator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This requires a non-trivial set of operators:

```
BehaviorSubject<Integer> ps = BehaviorSubject.create();

TestScheduler s = Schedulers.test();

ps.timestamp(s)
.buffer(4, 1)
.takeUntil(b -> {
    if (b.size() == 4) {
        long diff = b.get(3).getTimestampMillis()
            - b.get(0).getTimestampMillis();
        if (diff < 3000) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
})
.doOnCompleted(() -> System.out.println("-->> Four clicks!"))
.subscribe();

System.out.println("Sending 3 clicks");

ps.onNext(1);
ps.onNext(2);
ps.onNext(3);

s.advanceTimeBy(4, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

System.out.println("Sending 4 clicks");

ps.onNext(4);
ps.onNext(5);
ps.onNext(6);
ps.onNext(7);
```

What I'd do is timestamp each source value, do a sliding buffer (after each source item, up to 4 entries), use takeUntil to check if the time difference between the buffer's first and last item is within 3 seconds and return true to complete the stream.

Comment: Great, thank you a lot. Sorry, but I need small help again. I need to call this method not once. I already changed your code for this. But there is a small point - I don't want to call it too often. Is there some operator to pass the one emit and don't pass any other for some time?